# .htaccess redirect index.php?q=* to index.php?q=* on another domain

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, modx

Why each page redirects to domain? I move dkcherta.ru -> dkchertanovo.ru and want for example `http://dkcherta.ru/index.php?id=80` -> `http://dkchertanovo.ru/index.php?id=80`

My .htaccess:

```
    Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?dkcherta\.ru$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://dkchertanovo.ru/%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^rss_afisha[/]?$ /index.php?id=230 [L]
RewriteRule ^rss_news[/]?$ /index.php?id=231 [L]

ErrorDocument 404 http://dkchertanovo.ru/
# For full documentation and other suggested options, please see
# http://svn.modxcms.com/docs/display/MODx096/Friendly+URL+Solutions
# including for unexpected logouts in multi-server/cloud environments

RewriteBase /              

# Сливка доменного имени 
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^dkchertanovo\.ru$ [NC]
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.dkchertanovo.ru/$1 [R=301,L]

RemoveHandler .php .htm .html
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .htm .html
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php .htm .html
php_flag register_globals off

# Fix Apache internal dummy connections from breaking [(site_url)] cache
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*internal\ dummy\ connection.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [F,L]

# Exclude /assets and /manager directories from rewrite rules
RewriteRule ^(manager|assets) - [L]

# For Friendly URLs
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA] 


### force www
    #RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.(.+)$ [NC]
    #RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
    #RewriteBase /


# Reduce server overhead by enabling output compression if supported.
#php_flag zlib.output_compression On
#php_value zlib.output_compression_level 5
```

Comment: Have you tried turning on debugging on the rewrite engine to see how requests are being interpreted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need multiple lines of these:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
```

Just put only once at the top and it should be effective for rest of the file.

Then to solve your problem move this rule on top of all other rules in your `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?dkcherta\.ru$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://dkchertanovo.ru%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: anubhava, No, moving this rule (RewriteRule ^(.*) http://dkchertanovo.ru/$1 [L,R=301]) to the top doesn't solve problem...

Comment: Make sure to use a different browser to test it. What URL are you entering to test this? Also in which directory exactly is this `.htaccess` placed?

Comment: .htaccess is in the root. try url - http://dkcherta.ru/index.php?id=301 - it redirects to the home page dkchertanovo.ru I use hosting redirect too, may be turn it off?

Comment: Yes please turn hosting redirect off and use code from edited answer.

Comment: Ok and are you sure that above code is `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess`?

Comment: VHOST_DOCUMENT_ROOT /home/srv28064/htdocs, but my .htaccess is in /home/srv28064/dkchertanovo

Comment: Well in that case it not correct location. Above code should be placed in `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` of `dkcherta.ru` domain.

Comment: I can't do this, because there are the same files for both domains, so  they use the same folder and .htaccess only one.

Comment: Which is fine but still you need to use: `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess`

Comment: I forgot to connect domain dkcherta to the same directory as dkchertanovo. Now still one problem - domain with www doesn't redirect - look url: www.dkcherta.ru/index.php?id=33

Comment: It is because `www.dkcherta.ru` is not pointing to same host as `dkcherta.ru` I did nslookup and found that `www.dkcherta.ru` points to `IP: 78.110.50.101` while `dkcherta.ru` points to `IP: 78.110.50.150` Don't they both need to same IP?

Comment: Great! Thank you so much, anubhava. Should turn off redirect on hosting account firstly, and prove that its IP doesn't still ip for redirect. You've solved my problem!